# How can I make sure that my PHP api can only be used by a specific javascript page

Tags: php, javascript, get, security

I have a PHP page ("An API") that does server-side stuff (e.g. entering info into a database) based on GET string input.

Would it be possible for me to secure it so that only the JavaScript code on a specific site can access the api, including securing it against, for example, someone typing into a JavaScript console while on the site?

Comment: I imagine this is why API's generally have an "API key." So that they can restrict its use to certain people, and track who is using it.

Comment: @Nick But when the api key is stored in javascript, isn't it visible to users/hackers?

Comment: yes, this is the fundamental problem with DRM. You could obfuscate it to make difficult but you can't make it impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is impossible to completely protect against that.

You may, however, make it more difficult. For example:

- Require the `Referer` header to point to that page (some browsers don't send `Referer`, however)
- You could also check for `X-Requested-With` being equal to `XMLHttpRequest` if the JS library you're using sets that.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but only partially. For example Google uses a method of API keys that are matched against $_SERVER["HTTP REFERER"], but these things can easily be forged. Just make sure that a user will need real authentication for things that need real security (updates/edits/deletes etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply if you are exposing a page to the public treat the input as untrusted. Asking users politely not look at the key doesn't work. Always **validate** whatever input you get against the credentials of the user.

I would use an established method (not a roll your own) to login with the credentials of the user and validate the input on the server side. There is no way on the client end to force the users not to take specific actions (say, calling your page or * cough * copy a music file * cough *). This technology would be called DRM or something similar

Another issue is that you are using GET requests to permanently alter state on the server. Don't do that: use a POST (or PUT or DELETE) request instead.